# How to use statsmodels get_rdataset?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Python's `statsmodels` library has `get_rdataset()` method that can fetch various datasets. Where is the list of datasets that can be fetched? How do I use it to load datasets?

The [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/datasets/statsmodels.datasets.get_rdataset.html) has no mention of which datasets are available. It merely says that `dataname: The name of the dataset you want to download` is a required parameter but does not mention which datanames are possible anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV containing meta information about all datasets may be found at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/datasets.csv which is defined as variable `index_url` in `_get_dataset_meta()` function in the [`statsmodels.datasets.utils`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/datasets/utils.html) module.

When this dataset is loaded, e.g. using pandas, its first 5 rows look like below.

```py
import pandas as pd
datasets = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/datasets.csv")
datasets.head()
```

[image: datasets]

As the [documentation shows](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/datasets/statsmodels.datasets.get_rdataset.html), the first argument of `get_rdataset()` is the dataname (recorded as Item in the meta dataset) and the second argument is the package name the dataset belongs to. So for example, the following retrieves the first dataset in the CSV (because the dataname is Affairs which is in the AER package).

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Affairs', 'AER', cache=True).data
df.head()
```

[image: Affairs]

---

The list of all available datasets can also be found [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/articles/data.html). This is also [referenced](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/datasets/index.html#using-datasets-from-r) in the *Using Datasets from R* section of the Datasets package documentation.

<sup>Thanks @Vitalizzare for pointing me to this repo.</sup>